# Cypress break outer foreach from an inside then

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach, cypress

I want to break my outermost each loop from inside a then loop. I tried return false but it is not working. Following is my code snippet:

```
cy.get('abc').each(($elm) => {
    if ($elm.text() == 'xyz') {
        cy.get('pqr').click().then(() => {
            if (cy.get('dgf').text() == "sdasd") {
                expect(value1).to.be.equal(value2)
                return false // I want to stop the outermost for each loop
//But even with return false it does not breaks the forEach
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @AlapanDas No error but it does not breaks the foreach (when return false is executed), keeps on iterating

Comment: How does this piece of code play into your test? I think there may be a better approach than looping to find text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if (cy.get('dgf').text() == "sdasd")` use `if ($('selector').text() == 'sdasd')`

```js
cy.get('abc').each(($elm) => {
  if ($elm.text() == 'xyz') {
    $('pqr').click()
    if ($('dgf').text() == 'sdasd') {
      expect(value1).to.be.equal(value2)
    }
    return false
  }
})
```

Comment: yeah. I made a type there, But even then the foreach does not breaks. That is my main concern

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by this - `I made a type there`. The problem I think whats happening here is you are mixing sync and async codes. I have updated the answer, can you try now ?

Comment: I meant "Typo".

Answer (score 0):

Try using a flag, I saw somewhere that breacking out of `.each()` needs an unconditional `return` value (i.e not inside the `if()`)

```js
cy.get('abc').each(($elm) => {

  let continue = true;

  if ($elm.text() == 'xyz') {
    cy.get('pqr').click()
    cy.get('dgf')                           // NO cy.get() in if()
      .invoke('text')
      .then(dgfText => {
        if (dgfText === "sdasd") {
          expect(value1).to.be.equal(value2)
          continue = false
        }
      })
    })
  }

  return continue;   // true will keep going, false will break out
})
```

I suspect that's not going to do it tho. Maybe a restructure to eliminate the `.each()`

```js
cy.get('abc')
  .filter((index, el) => el.innerText === 'sdasd') // instead of each() and if()
  .then(() => {
    cy.get('pqr').click()
    cy.get('dgf')                           // NO cy.get() in if()
      .invoke('text')
      .then(dgfText => {
        if (dgfText === "sdasd") {
          expect(value1).to.be.equal(value2)
        }
      })
    })
  })
```